# Best method to clear list and dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Code:

```
num_of_iterations_for_outer_loop = 2
num_of_iterations_for_inner_loop = 3
data = []

for j in range(num_of_iterations_for_outer_loop):
    lst2 = []
    for k in range(num_of_iterations_for_inner_loop):
        lst1 = {}
        lst1['1'] = "first_value"  # these are not default, in my original code they are coming from some other values after calculation
        lst1['2'] = "second_value"
        lst1['3'] = "third_value"

        lst2.append(lst1)

    value = {'values':lst2}
    data.append(value)
```

In the outer loop I have to clear `lst2` list again and again for reusing it.

In the inner loop I have to clear `lst1` dictionary again and again for reusing it.

I know 2 methods of clearing a list:

1. `del lst2[:]`
2. `lst2 = []`

and 1 method for clearing a dictionary:

1. `lst1 = {}`

But I don't know differences between these methods and which one I should use.

Is there any other method to clear the list and dictionary? And is that better method, and why?

Is there any better method to write the whole code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a brief idea of what each method does:

1. `lst2 = []` does **not** actually clear the contents of the list. It just creates a new empty list and assign it to the name `lst2`. Then it is the task of GC to delete the actual contents based on the remaining references.

   ```
   >>> a = [1,2,3]
   >>> b = a
   >>> a = []
   >>> a
   []
   >>> b
   [1, 2, 3]
   ```
2. `del lst2[:]` clears the contents of the list *in-place*.

   ```
   >>> a = [1,2,3]
   >>> b = a
   >>> del a[:]
   >>> a
   []
   >>> b
   []
   ```

   Note that the other list b also gets cleared because the contents are deleted in-place.
3. `lst1 = {}` is same as point 1. It creates an empty dictionary and assigns the reference to the name `lst1`.

Another method to clear the list in-place is:

```
lst2[:] = []
```

Answer (score 1):

The differences between your two methods of "clearing" the list is that the first operates *in-place*, deleting the contents of the *original list object*, while the second simply creates a *new list object* and assigns it to the same name. You must use the second version here, otherwise all of the lists in your dictionary will be copies of the same emptied list at the end:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> d = {'a': l}
>>> del l[:]
>>> d
{'a': []}
```

Similarly, you can `del` all the key-value pairs from a dictionary, but you would have the same problem. As you are putting the original container objects into some other container, you should create a new container by assignment (e.g. `lst1 = {}`) in each loop.

> Is there any better method to write the whole code ?

I don't know what else you're doing with the data, but the dictionary `value` may be unnecessary, and a three-tuple of the innermost data could be sufficient:

```
data = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], [(7, 8, 9), ...], ...]
```

Comment: The `dict.clear()` method will quickly remove all the items in a dictionary in-place.

Answer (score 0):

Assignments are pretty much good and efficient methods to clear list or dict.

`my_dict = {}`

and `my_list = []`

Nothing fancy needed.

Comment: Neither of those statement actually clear the contents of the corresponding objects. They just create new, empty, containers and assign them to the each name. I believe the OP want it done _in-place_.

Comment: @martineau I bet they don't, that way they'll just end up with `data` containing a whole bunch of references to the same list containing a whole bunch of references to the same dictionary and will be right back here complaining that they only ever see the last values repeated over and over again.